# NoLinkedYoutubeAccount error from Google Data API

Tags: youtube-api, google-api, youtube-data-api

I have been tasked with integrating our internal video system with YouTube through the Data API, such that we can use the in-browser and server video upload facilities. I have linked a YouTube channel to a Google account, which is then linked to a Cloud Console account which contains the OAuth2 details.

However, when I authenticate using the Cloud Console account and try to upload a video, I get a NoLinkedYoutubeAccount error. Here are some screenshots of the linked account (I have been asked to blur the usernames and IDs but they do actually match up):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L3c4.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to link anything having to do with your YouTube channel to the same account that's used for the Cloud (Developers) Console. It *shouldn't* hurt, but it's not necessary.

Ensure that you go through the OAuth 2 flow using the credentials of a valid YouTube channel (which, again, doesn't have to be registered with the Cloud Console) and that you choose the appropriate option if you see the OAuth 2 channel picker (see http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api.html)

If you're still having trouble, try this as a sanity check: use the [API Explorer](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet&mine=true&_h=1&) to make a youtube.channels.list(mine=true, part='snippet') call, and authenticate with the same credentials using the little OAuth 2 toggle switch in the upper right. Do you get a response back?

Comment: Thanks - I'll give this a try when the project resumes next week